# 3 fates of this matter

Tags: homework, food, bioenergetics

When an animal eats something, it obtains matter and energy right? But, what are the 3 possible fates of the matter and 3 possible fates energy. I don't understand what they are even asking. What would be the 3 possible fates of each.

Comment: Please tag this as homework question.

Answer (score 3):

I think the poster wants only a simple answer, so I am going to answer in simple terms. The fates can be -

1 Used in cellular respiration as fuel and some amount can be converted to useful energy which can be used to build other substances and some energy can be lost as heat.

2.The animal can become prey for other animal.

3.The animal throws away some matter as feces.

Comment: I understand the matter portion but, the energy can be lost as heat? I get that it can be used to create substances in the body. And that is only 2 fates of the energy.

Comment: @John it can be passed on from the animal to the prey.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this video might help you:

[Matter and Energy in Organisms](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q52qtdrvah8)